# backward filling with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply a backward filling on a particular column of a dataframe  with the following condition: I have that the "colum_A" can assume only four values, called A, B, C, D and,  the backward filling should work as in the following:

```
if the first not NaN is A, then backward_filling with A;

if the first not NaN is B, then backward_filling with B;

if the first not NaN is C, then backward_filling with B;

if the first not NaN is D, then backward_filling with C;

if the column_A only contains NaN, then backward_filling with D
```

For example:

Input DF:

```
colum_A
 NaN
 NaN
 B
 B
 C
 C
```

Output DF:

```
colum_A
 B
 B
 C
 C
 D
 D
```

Please, any help would be very appreciated. 
Best Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with `bfill` by condition:

```
#get mask for back filling NaNs
m = df['colum_A'].isnull()
d = {'A':'A','B':'B','C':'B','D':'C'}
#D if all values NaN
df['colum_B'] = 'D' if m.all() else np.where(m, df['colum_A'].map(d).bfill(),df['colum_A'])
#alternative
#df['colum_B'] = 'D' if m.all() else df['colum_A'].mask(m, df['colum_A'].map(d).bfill())
print (df)
   colum_A colum_B
0      NaN       B
1      NaN       B
2        B       B
3        A       A
4      NaN       B
5        C       C
6        C       C
7      NaN       C
8      NaN       C
9      NaN       C
10       D       D
11       D       D
12       A       A
13       C       C
14     NaN       A
15       A       A
16     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Yes. it worked. Many Thanks Jezrael. Please, could you provide a bit more info about what np.where does in this particular  case?

Comment: Sure, function [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) working like if else but with arrays. I think link hope more.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. Very appreciated.